# Error trying to get specific information from a user (json). - Future<dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to find out if there is a specific user in the bank. I intend to get this user's information and give them the option to update their information or not.

For that, I'm bringing his identifier from the previous page and trying to get his data like this:

```
  Future<List>? _list;
.
.

  @override
  void initState() {
    _list = widget.userServices.searchUser(widget.cpf);
    super.initState();
  }
```

This returns me a json correctly.

This is my service to get a user's data:

```
  searchUser(cpf) async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(
          Uri.parse(BaseUrl.baseUrl + 'api/user/buscaProdutorPorCPF/$cpf'));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return json.decode(response.body);
      } else {
        throw Exception("Error");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Finally, I'm trying to display the information with this example code:

```
@override
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _list,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print(snapshot);
        if (snapshot.hasData)
          return _buildBody(snapshot.data);
        else if (snapshot.hasError)
          return _buildErrorPage(snapshot.error);
        else
          return _buildLoadingPage();
      },
    );
  }

   Widget _buildBody(List userList) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Employee Title = ${userList[0].nome}'),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: userList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(userList[index].email!),
            );
          },
        ),
      );

  Widget _buildErrorPage(error) => Material(
        child: Center(
          child: Text("ERROR: $error"),
        ),
      );

  Widget _buildLoadingPage() => Material(
        child: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
```

But I'm getting the following error:

[image]

I appreciate if anyone can help me analyze this error!

Comment: You can give try by adding return type on `searchUser(cpf)` also check on console by print/debug

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't quite understand.

Comment: try `Future<List<User>>? searchUser(cpf){...}`

Answer (score 0):

I think modifying the code like this:

```
return FutureBuilder(
   //rest of code
);
```

and

```
Widget _buildBody(List userList) => //rest of code
```

will resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I made the modifications you suggested, but I still get the same error. "But got one of type '_Future<dynamic>'". I also updated the question.

Comment: You probably got that error because of this: `Future<List<User>>? _list;`. Try this `late Future _list`  or `var _list` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but there's one other detail... here on this line: return _buildBody(snapshot.data); The snapshot.data is in error. The argument type 'Object?' cannot be assigned to parameter type 'List<dynamic>'.

Comment: Can you do `print(_list.runtimeType)` and tell me the answer?

Comment: When I do print(snapshot) I get the json, but print(_list.runType) gives an error... The 'runType' getter is not set to the 'Future<dynamic>' type.
Try importing the library that defines 'runType', either correcting the name to the name of an existing getter or defining a getter or field called 'runType'

Comment: My bad, there was an error in my last comment it is `runtimeType`. Just print `snapshot.runtimeType`.

Comment: result: AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>

Comment: Well...Modify again like this `late Future<List> _list` and `_list  = widget.userServices.searchUser(widget.cpf) as List;` and check.

Comment: I changed it, but snapshot.data still has an error, I tried snapshort.data as List, but it doesn't work! It gives this error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: no indices are valid: 0